# Sorting in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, oracle11g

I have a  `select` query in Oracle SQL which returns the table with the results

```
Location     count  
 site1       95000
 site2       556900
 site3       65600
```

I have then used the floor function `(floor/1000)` to obtain last 3 digits and append it with K+ using `floor(count/1000) || 'K+' as count` . Once done with that, am getting a table like this

```
Location    count  
site1       95K+
site2       556K+
site3       65K+
```

Now the issue is, when am sorting the result table using the `order by count desc` it is sorting like this

```
Location    count  
site1       95K+
site3       65K+
site2       556K+
```

The sorting is happening by considering the 1st digit I guess. I need the result to be generated like this while sorting in descending order.

```
Location    count  
site2       556K+
site1       95K+
site3       65K+
```

Is there a way to achieve this result? Any suggestions

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using.

Comment: ORDER BY the original count, have another column alias for the second "count"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatted value is a string and it will be sorted as string (e.g. `10K+` comes before `2K+` in dictionary order sorted ascending). Place the formatted value in `SELECT` clause but order by original value in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT Location, FLOOR(count/1000) || 'K+' AS k_formatted_count
FROM ...
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can simply do:

```
order by count(*) desc
```

That is, even though you are modifying the `count()` value in the `select`, you can still order by the actual count.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
select location,floor(count/1000)||'K' as count
from tablename
order by floor(count/1000) desc
```

Comment: This should work. The reason behind the odd behavior in the original query is that by concatenating `'K'` after your number, you are forcing the DBMS to consider the value a string, and when ordering strings, you just compare letters 1 by 1 instead of as whole like you would with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already been told what to do (just to repeat: `order by count(*) desc`), here's an example which shows how you might deal with such values (combined of numbers and letters), generally:

- you'd extract numeric part (I used `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, although simple `SUBSTR + INSTR` would work just fine in this example),
- apply `TO_NUMBER` to it (otherwise you'd still be sorting *strings* and get a wrong result)

---

```
SQL> with test (loc, num) as
  2    (select 'site1',  95000 from dual union all
  3     select 'site2', 556900 from dual union all
  4     select 'site3',  65600 from dual
  5    )
  6  select loc,
  7         floor(sum(num) / 1000) || 'K+' cnt    --> SUM represents your COUNT
  8  from test
  9  group by loc
 10  order by to_number(regexp_substr(cnt, '^\d+')) desc;

LOC        CNT
---------- ------------------------------------------
site2      556K+
site1      95K+
site3      65K+

SQL>
```